# how to send JSON in post api using Alomofire SWIFT

Tags: iphone, json, swift, alamofire

I need to send JSON format in post api using alamofire in swift. Way data need to send is

```
{
"data": [{
    "id": "1015683997",
    "name": "Pawel"
}, {
    "id": "108350039247",
    "name": "Randeep"
}, {
    "id": "115607797616",
    "name": "Mohit"
}]
}
```

And way i am able to generate as of now is:

```
["data": {
data =     (
            {
        id = 101583997;
        name = "Pawel";
    },
            {
        id = 108359247;
        name = "Randeep";
    },
            {
        id = 11567616;
        name = "Mohit ";
    }
);
}
]
```

Using the below mentioned way to generate json format.

```
for i in 0..<self.arrFriendsList.count
    {

        let dictFrndList:[String: AnyObject] = [
            "id" : arrFriendsList[i].valueForKey("id")!,"name" : arrFriendsList[i].valueForKey("name")!
            ]

        arrFrndList.addObject(dictFrndList)
    }
```

Then,

```
let dictFBFrndList: [String: AnyObject] = [

        "data":arrFrndList
    ]
```

Then,

```
let params: [String: AnyObject] = [

        "access_token" : accessToken,
        "data":dictFBFriends
    ]
```

So, please guide me. i have already spend more than a day on it. thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no mention of `access_token` in the JSON target. You are putting twice `data` (as a key)

Comment: That is not the concern, issue is when dictionary adding to array format changes not remains in JSON format. So, how can i maintain that.

Comment: I don't understand your real issue. You need to clarify. Is it because of the `({[` that are different?

Comment: @Larme The issue was format of data sending was not in JSON.

Comment: I don't understand which part you have a problem with either. You should probably rephrase your question. Also, you mention Alamofire, but you haven't included the call to it.

Comment: @Andreas My question is clear if you read question from starting, format required and format i had was clearly mentioned.

Comment: @iPhone6 Three answers, none accepted. And one answer is from you (?). Your definition of "clear" doesn't seem to have produced the desired results. If your answer is actually part of your question, then I think I know the problem. But it's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed this way

```
let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(arrFriendsList, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)

    let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String

    print(jsonString)

    let params: [String: AnyObject] = [

        "access_token" : accessToken,
        "data":jsonString
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I second what Larme said, you should post "arrFrndList" at the params with key "data" but not dictFBFrndList.

Comment: this is not a solution, requirement is to convert format in to json.

Answer (score 0):

```
let options = NSJSONWritingOptions()
    let data = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: options)
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"http:/myurl.com")

    if let str = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String {
        print(str)
    }
    mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    mutableURLRequest.setValue("your_access_token", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = data
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest).responseJSON(){
        json in
        if let value = json.result.value {
            let _json = JSON(value)
            if (!_json.isEmpty){
                print(_json)
            }
        }
    }
```

you can check how to seen your JSON array this code. Look at 5th cell code. This code will write your json array for you in output screen and you can coppy from there and paste in [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) then you will see how to send data.

Maybe this way can help you .